# How to add icons on searchable on react native material design toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-design, material-ui

Now I am developing react native app using material design, I am using react-native-material-ui package.

However, I can't add some icons in searchable on toolbar.(on searchable function).
like this link : https://material.io/design/navigation/search.html#expandable-search
please help me about this.
Thanks

Comment: please see this link, I wanna build like this link:https://material.io/design/navigation/search.html#expandable-search

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code in this link. Please check:--- 
 https://snack.expo.io/rkhB5Jog7

Comment: As you see this link, this is only to add on initial search component. when I click the search icon, I can't add icons. if you can do, please share your some code. thanks